# Number of points at which $f(x)=\max({-|x|,-\sqrt{1-x^2} })$ is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f\colon (-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x)=\max({-|x|,-\sqrt{1-x^2} })$. Find the number of points at which $f$ is not differentiable.

Can anyone solve this problem without sketching a graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function can only fail to be differentiable in points where $|x|$ or $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ arte not differentiable (this gives you $x=0$) or points of intersection of these two curves (you get 2 other points). These are the candidates, now you must check that $f$ is indeed not differentiable at those 3 points.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid sketching a graph? I can understand your wanting to do **more** than sketch a graph, but surely sketching a graph is a useful first step?

Comment: Sir, I know that sketching a graph is very useful but sometimes for me  it is difficult to  sketch a graph of an unfamiliar function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your interval, the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is differentiable everywhere. The function $|x|$ fails to be differentiable at $0$. Further points where differentiability can fail are those where $f(x)$ changes from one formula to the other.

You have that $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ at those points where $-|x|\leq-\sqrt{1-x^2}$. This is the same as $\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq|x|$. As everything is positive, this is the same as $1-x^2\leq x^2$, or $x^2\geq\tfrac12$. Thus
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{1-x^2},&\ |x|\geq\tfrac1{\sqrt2},\\ \ \\ -|x|,&\ |x|<\tfrac1{\sqrt2}
\end{cases}
$$
The lateral derivatives at $x=\tfrac12$ are 
$$
\lim_{x\to\tfrac1{\sqrt2}} -x=-1,\ \ \ \ \lim_{x\to\tfrac1{\sqrt2}}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1,
$$
so they don't agree and $f$ is not differentiable at $x=\tfrac1{\sqrt2}$. A similar computation shows the same for $x=-\tfrac1{\sqrt2}$.

Thus, $f(x)$ fails to be differentiable at three points: 
$$
x=0, \ \ x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}. 
$$